# Increment row MySql Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to increment row in MySQL database like this

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()

i = 0
for row in rows:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE Table SET order = %s WHERE name = 'JAMES'", (i,))
    db.commit()
    i += 1
```

But at the end order for all of the items is 19, and the length of `rows` is 20. How can I have it go form 0 to 19, I though if I `commit()` after each loop this would be solved?

Thanks

Comment: Without `where` clause, the `UPDATE` statement will update all records.

Comment: @falsetru its there ill add it to the question I just left it out by accident

Comment: Is it always 'JAMES'? Then, the same records will be updated multiple times.

Comment: @falsetru why does it matter what the WHERE clause is? No it is not always james, it is getting a different row every time

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `cursor.execute("UPDATE Table SET order = %s WHERE name = %s", (i, row.name))`.  `WHERE` clause matters.

Comment: @falsetru you are right, thanks if you want to post as answer for other users and ill make as correect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you meant something like this (WHERE clause change for rows):

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    cursor.execute("UPDATE Table SET order = %s WHERE name = %s", (i, row.name))
    db.commit()
```

Otherwise, `order` fields or one record is updated multiple times.